# Some doubts related explicit page mapping in Spring MVC, how exactly work?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following question about how is implemented the routing in this particular Spring MVC configuration.

So, into a file named **mvc-config.xml** I have the following MVC configuration:

```
<!-- other option is UrlFilenameViewController -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="/index"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/index.html" view-name="/index"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/html5.html" view-name="/html5/html5"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/about.html" view-name="/about"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/admin/admin.html" view-name="/admin/admin"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/login.html" view-name="/form/login"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/denied.html" view-name="/error/denied"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/rest.html" view-name="/rest/rest"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/file.html" view-name="/file/file"/> <!-- Mapping per l'empio dell'upload file -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/cookieView.html" view-name="/cookie/cookieView"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/jstl.html" view-name="/jstl/jstl"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/audiovideo.html" view-name="/audiovideo/audiovideo"/>    
<mvc:view-controller path="/jdbc.html" view-name="/jdbc/jdbc"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/orm.html" view-name="/orm/orm"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/scope.html" view-name="/scope/scope"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/maintenance.html" view-name="/maintenance"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/security.html" view-name="/security/security"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/controller.html" view-name="/controller/controllerView"/>
```

I never seen this kind of settings and I always used the controller classes (annotated con **@Controler**) that contains methods annotated with **@RequestMapping** that handle specific HttpRequest toward specific resources and that return the logical view name.

So, in the application on which I am working seems that the MVC logic is pretty differente.

It seems to me that I have not **controller classes** and that the routing is explicitelly handled.

So for example I have:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/file.html" view-name="/file/file"/>
```

that I think means: handle all the request toward the **/file.html** resource showing the **file.jsp** page that is inside the **/file/** folder of the view directory.

And infact into the view directory I have the **/file/file.jsp** page that is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="page" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<page:template>
    <jsp:attribute name="title">
        Spring MVC File Upload Controller Example
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
            <c:url value="/uploadFile" var="fileUploadControllerURL" />
            <h1><b>Spring MVC FileUploadController Example</b></h1> <br/>
            <form action="${fileUploadControllerURL}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table>
                    <tr><td><b>File:</b></td><td><input type="file" name="file"></td><td><input type="submit" value="Press to upload the File"></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form> 
            <br/><br/> 
            <c:url value="/excel" var="excelController" />
            <a href="${excelController}">Excel</a><br/>     
            <c:url value="/pdf" var="PDFController" />
            <a href="${PDFController}">PDF</a> 
    </jsp:body>
</page:template>
```

So, as you can see, insdie this page I have something like:

```
<c:url value="/excel" var="excelController" />
<a href="${excelController}">Excel</a><br/>
```

What exactly means?

It seems to me that the first line put the **/excel** value inside a variable named **excelController** and that then this is used into the **href**

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<c:url>` is a very useful and powerful jspl-tag. In general you are right:

```
<c:url value="/excel" var="excelController" />
<a href="${excelController}">Excel</a><br/>
```

> It seems to me that the first line put the /excel value inside a variable named excelController and that then this is used into the href

But some details are missing: the value that is stored in `excelController` is not exactly `/excel`, but the domain relative url for `/excel`, and it will maybe have a sessionId paramater (depending how your session tracking is configured).

For example, assume that your run a localhost tomcat with this app, called "MyApp" and using cookies to track the session, then `excelController` will be: `/MyApp/excel`